# Compare two columns in DB2

Tags: sql, select, db2

I need help with a query DB2.

My table looks like this:

```
IP_ID         IP_TYPE_CDE UPDT_DT_TM                
------------- ----------- --------------------------
47560147.          39 2012-11-06-04.16.21.000000
47560147.         319 2013-06-12-16.54.09.000000
47560002.          39 2012-11-06-04.16.21.000000
47560002.         319 2013-06-12-16.54.09.000000
47560003.          39 2012-11-06-04.16.21.000000
47560003.          39 2013-06-12-16.54.09.000000
```

I need to scan the database, catch all the IP_ID and compare it to that IP_ID had change in IP_TYPE_CDE.

I.e., in this case it should return only IP_ID 47560147 and 47560002.

Comment: `select ip_id from yourtable group by ip_id, ip_type having count(distinct ip_type) > 1`?

Answer (score 1):

You could group by `ip_id` and filter by a `having` clause that counts the distinct number of `ip_type_cde`s:

```
SELECT   ip_id
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY ip_id
HAVING   COUNT (DISTINCT ip_type_cde) > 1
```

Comment: This query does not bring any results.

`select ip_id from cdw.IP_HIST group by ip_id , ip_type_cde having count (distinct ip_type_cde ) > 1

IP_ID
-------------

  0 record ( s) selected .`

Comment: @JohnnAmancio - well yeah.  The statement you've just posed in your comment added `ip_type_cde` to the grouping, which means the `HAVING` clause will **always** return 1.  Whatever did you do that for?